# Dependency Property GetValue in different class

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, getvalue

so I'm having some problems getting my Depency Properties working. But in fact only if I'm trying to access them from a different class.

For example I'm doing a check to ping a server and define the corresponding Dependency Property:

```
        public static DependencyProperty PingStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PingState", typeof(bool),
        typeof(MainWindow));

    public bool PingState
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(PingStateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PingStateProperty, value);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PingState"));
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to get the value from the Dependency Property in a different class (specifically a user control). So I'm having another class where I'm trying to get the value like this:

```
    public void MethodInClass2()
    {
        bool ping = (bool)GetValue(MainWindow.PingStateProperty);
```

What I'm doing wrong here? The thing that bugs me is: It's working when I call GetValue in the same class. It doesn't give me a compile error or something like that, it seemingly just don't pass the right value (In class 1 where the DP is defined I can check for the value and get "true" as expected but when trying to do the same in class 2 I'm just getting "false" everytime).

Do I need an Attached Property in such a case? Tried a bit with them also but to no avail unfortunately.

Greetings

Comment: You're getting the value of the wrong instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of the property, you need the instance that holds the value, as stated in the previous comments and answers. Get the instance using a setter/singleton or whatever works for you. Dependency/attached properties won't solve your problem. (If you then want to bind to the property, use dependency property.)

Comment: This actually really got me. Thing is, I don't need to bind it there, I just need the value for further analysation in the user control. Will post an answer on how I've done it. Thanks and marked as answer (although the title may be a bit misleading now...).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the value unless you have set it before. And you can only set that value if the target object is of the same type or a derived one unless it is an attached property. Calling `GetValue` like this does *not* get the property from the main window, it gets the property from the current instance (your user control).

*Never* place additional code in the CLR wrapper (`public bool PingState`). It's not called by the binding system or otherwise when accessing the property properly. To get a property changed callback use the [metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata(v=vs.110).aspx) upon [property registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer first. The mentioning of the CLR wrapper issue is right of course, I'll change that then. But about the actual thing: I see, I need an attached property then. But the usual tutorials I can find on this are doing that from the same thread. How to call it from a dfiferent one (my UserControl)?

Comment: @CuttingWide Start reading here: [Attached Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @CuttingWide: If your UserControl is actually on another thread you are probably doing it wrong, it complicates everything. As you accepted another answer i assume you just mean access from another class here.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @aQsu I was able to sort this out differently. I'm using now a Singleton to get the instance like the following:

```
        private static MainWindow _instance;

    public static MainWindow Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new MainWindow();

            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

Then simply calling in the UserControl

```
            bool ping = MainWindow.Instance.PingState;
```

Comment: I would suggest not making the main window a singleton. There already is a prominent singleton, namely the `Application`, so i usually define such things as an instance property of the `App` class, which you can get via `Application.Current` (needs to be cast, so i usually override `Current` with the cast included in the `App` class, so `App.Current` returns an `App` instance.)

Comment: Application also has a `MainWindow` property (relevant for `ShutdownMode`), you can just set that to your instance, though you might also want to hide the property with a correctly typed instance.